# Built-in Context-and-Input-to-Output-Hashing in Compilers

Tags: compiler, caching, hashing

Why doesn't (open source) compilers contain builtin funtionality for (shared) caching and reuse-fetching (using SHA1-hash of compiler-version, build-flags, target-platform and inputs) of executable output objects (ELF or COFF) similar to what `ccache` does and `scons`?

Many large software projects would benefit enormously in required build-disk-space and -time if this was present in, say GCC.

Comment: Because that's the job of a build system, not the job of a batch compiler?

Comment: Take a look add Ada and gnatmake and you'll understand why this is important and why most build tools of today create unnecessary burdens for the developer when dealing with dependency checking.

Comment: Recompiling dependencies but nothing else is a nontrivial problem with *some* languages, yes, but I don't see anything in your proposal addressing that.